# How to link an image to two different email addresses?

Tags: html

I want one of my images to be anchored (via a mailto link) to two separate email addresses.

Could I put two anchor blocks with different mailtos around the image? Is there a way to link to multiple addresses from one image?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `;` to separate the email addresses. As simple as that.

```
<a href="mailto:a@b.com; b@c.com"><img src="image-src.jpg"/></a>
```

Then in between the `<a>` and `</a>` you can add whatever you like. No limit. So you can have multiple images, text. Whatever you like.

Comment: @user3712683 not a problem. The mailto essentially just takes the information after `mailto:` and transposes it to the recipient box of your email. So the same way in outlook if you want to email multiple people you separate each email with `;` it applies here too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different *parts* of the image to be clickable and open emails to different email addresses, you could use [client side image maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map#Client-side_image_map):

```
<img src="image.png" usemap="#mailtomap">
<map name="mailtomap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,30" href="mailto:a@b.com">
      <area shape="rect" coords="0,30,200,60" href="mailto:b@c.com">
</map>
```